# Boolean object shows up in render

Tags: rendering, modifiers

my boolean object which is used by a bunch of objects, shows up in the final render. The collection which it belongs to, is set to invisible in the render. When I move the boolean object away so that it doesn't affect any other object, it renders as invisible. What can I do to fix this? Will it maybe help to change all the boolean modifiers to exact instead of fast, and is there a way to only copy one modifier to other objects, and not all of the modifiers?

Thanks.
[image: My model]
[image: Boolean moved so it doesn't intersect, but still in camera view]
[image: Boolean object shows up in render]

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. There were some window frames where the boolean modifier was set to exact instead of fast. I changed it them to fast. I also fixed the window frames meshes to make sure there were no open faces etc. Works now.[image]